# Is specifying EndStreamPrimitive() necessary in Geometry shader with streams

Tags: opengl, glsl, geometry-shader

EndStreamPrimitive() can only be used in case of Geometry shader with streams.
Geometry shader with streams can only emit GL_POINTS.
But In GL_POINTS, each vertex itself is a primitive.

So what is the point of having a function like EndStreamPrimitive()?
Just specifying EmitStreamVertex() when primitive type = GL_POINT means end of primitive.

My next question is What is max_vertices in a Geometry shader?

layout(points, max_vertices = 6) out;

I suppose it is the maximum number of vertices a Geometry shader will emit (irrespective of weather it is using streams or not).
If I have 2 streams in my Geometry shader, and I emit 2 vertices to stream 0, 3 vertices to stream 1. should the value of max_vertices be set to 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, `EndStreamPrimitive (...)` currently has no use; likely provided simply for consistency with the non-stream GLSL design. If the restriction on `points` being the only type of output primitive is lifted it may become useful in the future.

---

To answer your second question, that is the maximum number of vertices you will ever emit in a single invocation of your GS. Geometry Shaders are different from other stages in that the size of their output data can vary at run-time. You could decide because of some condition at run-time that you want to output 8 vertices to stream 1 -- GLSL needs to know an upper-bound and it cannot figure that out if your flow control is based on a variable set elsewhere.

There are implementation limits set on ***both*** the number of vertices (`GL_MAX_GEOMETRY_OUTPUT_VERTICES`) a GS invocation can emit and the sum total number of vector components (`GL_MAX_GEOMETRY_TOTAL_OUTPUT_COMPONENTS`). These limits are also defined in the shading language.

#### Implementations must support the following minimums:

```
const int gl_MaxGeometryOutputVertices        = 256;
const int gl_MaxGeometryTotalOutputComponents = 1024;
```

If your shader exceeds those limits, you will need to split it into multiple invocations. You can either do that using multiple draw calls or you can have GL4+ automatically invoke your GS multiple times:

```
layout (invocations = <num_invocations​>) in;
```

You can determine which invocation the GS is performing by the value of `gl_InvocationID​` (GL4+).